# Showing one-to-many relationship

Tags: excel

I am trying to present data from SQL Server in an Excel sheet so that operational users can understand the data. Here's how the data looks in SQL Server:

```
PersonId    Name        Address     Role    Organization
1           John Smith  123 Main St Donor   Library
1           John Smith  123 Main St Member  Ballet
2           Jane Doe    333 Main St Member  Orchestra
```

As you can see the database contains a one-to-many relationship between a person and the role they play in an organization.

In my Excel I want to show the person record only once and somehow show that this person plays multiple roles and these are the roles.

Comment: How many different roles are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of group concatenation methods out there. Some use dynamic sql and others use xml. Here's a simple one if you have a short list of roles known in advance. And this way you can control the order of the listing really easily.

```
select *, 
    (
    select
        substring(
            coalesce(min(case when r.Role = 'Donor'  then ', Donor'  end), '') +
            coalesce(min(case when r.Role = 'Member' then ', Member' end), '') +
            ...
            coalesce(min(case when r.Role = 'XXXXXX' then ', XXXXXX' end), '')
            , 3, 300)
    from PersonRoles pr
    where pr.PersonId = p.PersonId
    ) as Roles
from Person p
```

I'm not sure how organization fits into your problem but it appears to me that it's part of the role. You should be able to use `pr.Role + ' ' + pr.Organization` in the `case` logic for that.